# rc calendar when I select the date in the calendar its not changing in the textbox

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, redux

I am new to rc calendar.

I am able to display rc-calendar but when I select the date in the calendar its not changing in the textbox.

So I debugged and looked into the various methods in their documents.
but not sure which method to use.

Can you tell me how to fix it so that in future I will fix it myself.

I think problem is due to this line input **value={moment(value).format('M/D/YY')}/>**

https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-b2d3rb?file=demo.js

```
 render() {
        const calendar = (<Calendar/>);
        return (
            <div>
                <DatePicker
                    animation="slide-up"
                    value={moment()}
                    disabled={false}
                    calendar={calendar}
                >{
                    ({value}) => {
                        return (
                           // <input value={value}/>
                            <input value={moment(value).format('M/D/YY')}/>
                        )
                    }
                }</DatePicker>
            </div>
        )
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here, your code is working, just you need set state by 'handleChange' method and pass parameter in 'moment' methos:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import Calendar from 'rc-calendar';
import DatePicker from 'rc-calendar/lib/Picker';
import 'rc-calendar/assets/index.css';
import moment from 'moment';

class CalendarPage extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      date: new Date(),
    };
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
}

handleChange(date) {
  console.log(date);
  this.setState({
    date: date,
  });
}

render() {
    const calendar = (<Calendar/>);
    return (
        <div>
            <DatePicker
                animation="slide-up"
                value={moment(this.state.date)}
                disabled={false}
                calendar={calendar}
                onChange={this.handleChange}
            >{
                ({value}) => {
                    return (
                        <input value={moment(value).format('M/D/YY')}/>
                    )
                }
            }</DatePicker>
        </div>
    )
  }
}

export default CalendarPage;
```

Comment: hey it worked can you tell me how you fixed...it would be great if you give comments to the code

Comment: when you select the date, you should set the date it into state by handleChange method and in 'moment(this.state.date)' method pass the state date in DatePicker component thats it,

if you are satisfied with my answer accept it